# Imitate multiple inheritance

Tags: inheritance, typescript, multiple-inheritance, mixins, prototypal-inheritance

There is a class `First` and constructor function `Second`. I'm trying to create a class `Both` as a child of both of them. More accurate, I'm copiing methods from constructor function prototype to child class prototype.

I do understand that it's not the real inheritance, but that's enough for me.

There is other problem. How can I make typescript to accept copied methods?

```
class First {
  someMethod() {
    console.log('someMethod from First');
  }
}

function Second() {
  console.log('Second');
}

Second.prototype.doSmth = function () { 
  console.log('doSmth from Second');
}

interface IBoth {
  someMethod()
  doSmth()
}

class Both extends First /* implements IBoth */ {
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor of Both');
    super();
    Second.call(this);
  }
}

for (let key in Second.prototype) {
  Both.prototype[key] = Second.prototype[key];
}
```

In fact I need to see the metods one level deepper:

```
class Final extends Both {
  doIt() {
    this.someMethod();
    //this.doSmth(); // How to make this call threated as correct?
    (this as any as IBoth).doSmth(); // That compiles, but it's awfull
  }
}
```

if in this case methods won't be visible in class `Both`, it's ok.

I've already tryed:

1. When writing

   ```
   class Both extends First implements IBoth {
   ```

   typesctipt says that I haven't implement interface methods.
2. Renaming `Both` to `_Both` and using

   ```
   var Both = _Both as typeof _Both;
   ```

   leaves same problems as original code, as `First` is never mentoned.
3. If I rename `Both` to `_Both` and write

   ```
   var Both = _Both as typeof IBoth;
   ```

   typescript can't find `IBoth`.

Are there some other ways to reach it?

---

You can try at http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground
**[Full code there](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('someMethod%20from%20First')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log('Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ASecond.prototype.doSmth%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20console.log('doSmth%20from%20Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IBoth%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMethod()%0D%0A%20%20doSmth()%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Both%20extends%20First%20%2F*%20implements%20IBoth%20*%2F%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('constructor%20of%20Both')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Second.call(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20key%20in%20Second.prototype)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Both.prototype%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20Second.prototype%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Final%20extends%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doIt()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.someMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20How%20to%20make%20this%20call%20threated%20as%20correct%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(this%20as%20any%20as%20IBoth).doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20That%20compiles%2C%20but%20it's%20awfull%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A(new%20Final).doIt()%3B)**

Add this line and run the code (copy code from right panel to your browser console):

```
(new Final).doIt();
```

Output when line `this.doSmth();` is not commented:

```
constructor of Both
Second
someMethod from First
doSmth from Second
doSmth from Second
```

---

PS: [Same question in Russian.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/473837/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Both extends First {
  constructor() {...}
  doSmth: typeof Second.prototype.doSmth;
}
```

[Demo](http://goo.gl/fhkYmD)

It's also better to have `Second` as a class instead of a function. Add a declaration file if that's a javascript module.

Lastly, and if you can't have types for `Second`, just add types for each function like this:

```
class Both extends First {
  constructor() {...}
  doSmth: () => void;
}
```

Comment: `Cannot find namespace 'Second'`

Comment: The syntax isn't exact. You might have to play with it a bit. Are you sure Second is already defined in the same file?

Comment: You just need to define the "doSmth" function inside the class "Both". That's it.

Comment: I've added a link to full code in the playground to the question. And about declaring a function - I've found a way (see the answer).

Comment: No, with `=` you get `this.doSmth = Second.prototype.doSmth;` in compiled version. So each instance contains a referense to the fuction in it. My version with `:` does not affect compiled code - it's just a typescript declaration. And I cope function to the prototype, so instanses do not have a referense themselves.

Comment: Well if you want it that way, change it to this: `doSmth: typeof Second.prototype.doSmth,`
Cleaner than an interface.

Comment: Seems like you get just `Function` with typeof. Check `both.doSmth(78);` - with `doSmth: typeof Second.prototype.doSmth` it's ok, but with `doSmth: () => void` typescript tells about signature mismatch. About interface - I really don't need it.

Comment: That's due to Second.prototype having type "any" I guess. For example, here you can see the type of `doSmth` is correct:
http://goo.gl/xTVD3V

Comment: The issue there was that you're using "function" instead of "class" for Second.

Comment: You replaced function via class :) Nice. Not the way I need, but it's good to know about this feature. Upvoted the answer.

Comment: Class is actually a function, only with syntactical sugar in Typescript. You should always prefer classes over setting "prototype" because that's the point of typescript after all. :)

Comment: ["we allow developers to use these techniques now, and compile them down to JavaScript"](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes). 
down to JavaScript means to a function. it's just a way improve type detection.

Comment: Yep, I know. But in fact I need this as a connection point beetween javascript and typescript code. By the way, classes in ES6 have special features - they are more than just fuctions, but that's not about typescript.

Comment: ah I got it. so in case the "Second" class is not in typescript you're better off with `doSmth: () => void`.

Comment: by the way, it could be easier to add a declaration file for "Second" as a class and just treat it as one. You'll gain type hinting for both Second and Both that way.

Comment: This way leads to errors if I need to override the method. http://stackoverflow.com/q/35658109/4928642

Answer (score 1):

Interface is not required. Just need to declare a prototype field via

```
doSmth: () => void
```

It's visible as a property, not as a method, but that's ok.

Full listing:

```
class First {
  someMethod() {
    console.log('someMethod from First');
  }
}

function Second() {
  console.log('Second');
}

Second.prototype.doSmth = function () { 
  console.log('doSmth from Second');
}

class Both extends First {
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor of Both');
    super();
    Second.call(this);
  }

  doSmth: () => void
}

for (let key in Second.prototype) {
  Both.prototype[key] = Second.prototype[key];
}

class Final extends Both {
  doIt() {
    this.someMethod();
    this.doSmth();
    //Both.prototype.doSmth(); // ok
    //Final.prototype.doSmth(); // ok
  }
}
```

PS: Should've google for `typescript class prototype variable` instead of different combinations about inheritance.